# .htaccess from main to subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I can't get the below redirection to work. It's redirecting properly when I enter mydomin.com in the address bar, but not when I enter www.mydomain.com

I want all access from www.mydomain.com and mydomain.com to go to sub1.mydomain.com.
Note that I have sub2, sub3, they have their own .htaccess files and these should not be affected.

```
redirectMatch 301 ^www\.mydoman\.com$ http://sub1.mydomain.com  
redirectMatch permanent ^www\.mydomain\.com$ http://sub1.mydomain.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.com$[OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub1.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: tried, it doesn't work. for both with and without 'www'. hmm...maybe something changed. my original redirect doesn't work too.

Comment: You could also use just `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$` instead of the 2 conditions. Still worth a +1 though.